Encoding of vp9 files with ffmpeg fails when the video dimensions are greater than 16256 pixels in any dimension
I'm trying to create a .webm video with the vp9 codec from scratch using the following command:
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=blue -vf "format=rgb24,scale=16255x16255" -c:v libvpx-vp9 -t 0.25 -b:v 32K -preset veryfast -loglevel trace -pix_fmt yuv420p -y b_part.webm

It works fine, but when I try using a larger video size, the process fails with the following error:
[libvpx-vp9 @ 0x56294fdf7540] [IMGUTILS @ 0x7ffd1877c2d0] Picture size 16260x16255 is invalid
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height

The documentation says that vp9 supports resolutions up to 65536x65536, but ffmpeg cannot do it.
Therefore, is there any way to create videos with the largest possible dimensions? I am also considering other software options, not just ffmpeg.

Try the standalone encoder.
